# Incorrect photon wavelength hitting electron

Tags: waves, photon-emission

We have learned in class that an electron only goes up to a higher energy level when something supplies it with the exact energy it needs to do so. The emission spectra seems to show that if a wavelength of light does not have that specific energy, it will just pass through.

What happens to the electron in this case? Does it go up and down without ever settling on an energy level or is it just unaffected?

Comment: It is possible, in intense laser beams, that multiple photons are absorbed at one time (look up, e.g., multi-photon ionization). So, it may depend.

Comment: It is also possible for the photon to excite an electron and still have some energy left over. This is rare, but it can happen. It is known as Raman scattering.

Comment: I should have said excite an atom or molecule rather than excite an electron.

Answer (score 2):

You have to realize that the incoming photon has to have the  energy between the energy level where the electron is residing in the atom, usually the ground state, and a higher energy level. If the photon does not fulfill this requirement the electron will stay at that ground energy level and the photon will pass unaffected.

You must keep in mind that it is the *whole atom*    that is interacting with the photon when it has the exact energies. [The atom absorbs and emits](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/chemistry/5-111-principles-of-chemical-science-fall-2008/readings-and-lecture-notes/lecnotes05.pdf) photons with the appropriate energy.

Comment: Ok, so it does just pass through. But this seems odd. Does this imply it is only possible to excite an electron with some discrete quantities of energy? What would happen if this was not about photons. What if the electron was just given a "wrong" value of energy in some other way. Would it still be unaffected?

Comment: The electron within the atom is bound, not independent.  There exists a width to the energy levels, they are not sharp. The atoms can interact with the outside of the atom world as a whole at every day energies, electromagnetically. One possibility is what your question is about, interacting with real photons/light. Another possibility is interacting with other atoms through the electric field which spills over because of the shape of the orbitals . https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital . The forces due to the variations in the positive and negative fields are what keep molecules  and

Comment: liquids and solids together because they are attractive ( the positive comes from the nucleus in the spaces where there is no negative spill).  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_force . When an atom hits an atom it can transfer enough energy to excite an electron or even ionize an atom. Adding heat to solids and liquids increases vibrations and interactions between atoms ( always electromagnetic) can transfer vibrational  kinetic energy to the molecules and atoms and break bonds and free electrons,  at very high temperatures creating plasmas  in the gas state

Comment: When the atom is given a "wrong" value of energy  the electron  is unaffected, it is cradled within the atom and only the exact ( within widths) energy can budge it.